# How to aling a text with an icon button vertically?

Tags: flutter, icons

I want to align a text and a button vertically inside a `DrawerHeader` like this:

[image]

and this is my code:

```dart
DrawerHeader(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: const Icon(Iconsax.arrow_left_2),
      ),
      Text(
        'Welcome',
        style: kH3TitleStyle.copyWith(
          color: AppColors.primaryColor,
        ),
      ),
      Text(
        userBox!.get(UserBoxStrings.userName),
        style: kH3TitleStyle.copyWith(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

The problem is due to the width of the icon button I cannot align the `Text` and the `IconButton` vertically, and I'm getting something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A material icon button has a default padding. You need to remove the padding by using padding: EdgeInsets.zero like this.

```
IconButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
)
```